# Connecting R to Valentina?

Tags: r, database

My company hosts their data in valentina and it doesn't seem like valentina is supported in R? I have tried to connect R to valentina to no avail. Please share your code if you're able to.

Since I only need a small portion of the data for analysis, I'm thinking about making a copy of the data in AWS and connecting R to it. I'm very limited in that expertise, so please give me your two-cents!

Comment: I'm affraid this question may be on topic on StackOverflow, but not here, because it is about coding and not about statistics. It's likely to be migrated or closed.